# API/Interface for Blob Storage in Java

Tags: java, blob, blobstore

I was wondering if there was an API or interface for Java that allows for access and operations on object/blob storage.

For example, Java has JMS as an API for which we can use whatever implementation we'd like. Ex, Azure Service Bus, ActiveMQ.

Does such an API exist for accessing blob data such as something stored in Azure Blob Storage? I want to be able to switch vendors in and out. Id prefer for it to be a standard Java SE/EE API. Im not sure if such a thing exists.

As of writing this, I have been unable to locate any. It may be that Java calls it something else? Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

> For example, Java has JMS as an API for which we can use whatever implementation we'd like. Ex, Azure Service Bus, ActiveMQ

Some technologies are having well established vendor-independent protocols, such as JDBC or JMS. For blob / object storage we will see in a few year which vendor will become dominant (I see multiple service providers supporting AWS S3 protocol or OpenStack).

> I want to be able to switch vendors in and out

If you want to stay provider-agnostic, maybe you can find a library providing an abstraction level, such as [Apache JClouds](https://jclouds.apache.org/).

Comment: Apache Jclouds may just be what I was looking for. Thanks!